# Mongo aggregate group by one array element

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("540dadfcf3116b60d401c314"),
  "value" : 2,
  "d_c_at" : [
    "2013",
    "201311",
    "2013w46",
    "20131116"
  ]
}
```

and I want to group them by the last element in the `d_c_at` array (`20131116`) which represent the year, month and day store as destructured date.

Here is what I have so far:

```
db.points.aggregate(
  { $match: { "d_c_at.0": '2014' } },
  { $group: { _id: "$d_c_at.0", value: { $sum: "$value" } } }
)
```

which return:

```
{ "_id" : [ ], "value" : 1207 }
```

I have tried using `$unwind` without success:

```
db.points.aggregate(
  { $match: { "d_c_at.0": '2014' } },
  { $unwind: "$d_c_at" },
  { $group: { _id: "$d_c_at", value: { $sum: "$value" } } }
)
```

Seems almost good but it also groups on other array elements:

```
{ ... }
{ "_id" : "20140519", "value" : 33 }
{ "_id" : "20140707", "value" : 36 }
{ "_id" : "20140330", "value" : 37 }
{ "_id" : "20140709", "value" : -28 }
{ "_id" : "20140620", "value" : 14 }
{ "_id" : "2014w9", "value" : -250 }
{ ... }
```

Expected output:

```
{ ... }
{ "_id" : "20140519", "value" : 33 }
{ "_id" : "20140707", "value" : 36 }
{ "_id" : "20140330", "value" : 37 }
{ "_id" : "20140709", "value" : -28 }
{ "_id" : "20140620", "value" : 14 }
{ ... }
```

Comment: Why are you storing the date this way? You can use [date expression operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators) to group on parts of a date.

Comment: Why not copy the match in the aggregate after the unwind? I'm not sure what the expected output should be.

Comment: @wdberkeley better performance when querying documents created on a particular year, week, day

Comment: @LarryBattle edited by question with expected output. Basically I want the sum of the `value` group on days.

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois: in order to achieve better performance, you have a) a multikey index, b) an additional unwind unwind stage in your aggregation (delaying an early match), c) massively increased data size, d) string matching. Sorry, but think again. Using data expression operators is _by far_ the better solution, on all levels.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg yes for aggregation it seems the right tool. For regular `find` query, it's useful since performing complex date queries (using `$or` for example) is not great. Having dates as an array of feature helps I think.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg inspired from http://fr.slideshare.net/gabriele.lana/mongodb-with-style Thoughts on this are more than welcome

Comment: I don't know your use cases, but if you need data, then do it properly, like `date:{dow:2,woy:9,full:ISODate[...]}` during insertion if you _really_ need real time queries. Otherwise, you can use `$project`and `$out` to create a table based on your source table using an aggregate which creates the required fields. Tested it for some 500k records, takes mere seconds on my laptop, compiling a spring app the same time.

Comment: I haven't looked carefully at the slides but I can tell you a lot of the advice is going to be wrong/obsolete because they are ancient (2011!) in MongoDB terms.

Comment: Make sense. Create separate collection seems to be a nice idea but I need those grouped data on a per user basis. Therefor it does not seem to be a scalable solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Though this might be achievable using aggregation, Your expected output is easily achievable using Map-reduce:
Assuming your d_c_at, always has 4 elements, or the 4th element being your group id criteria, as your example structure depicts.

emit key as the 4th element, so that the documents are grouped by the 4th element of "d_c_at".

```
var map = function(){emit(this.d_c_at[3],{"sum":this.value});}
```

Once this is done, calculate the sum:

```
var reduce = function(id,Arr){
var sum = 0;
for(var i=0;i<Arr.length;i++)
    {
        var obj = Arr[i];
        var value = obj.sum;
        sum = sum+value;
    }
    return {"sum":sum};
}
```

Dump the result onto "output".

```
db.test.mapReduce(
                     map,
                     reduce,
                     { out: "output" }
                   )
```

o/p:

```
> db.output.find()
{ "_id" : "20131116", "value" : { "sum" : 6 } }
{ "_id" : "20131117", "value" : { "sum" : 6 } }
```

Sample i/p used:

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "value" : 2,
  "d_c_at" : [
    "2013",
    "201311",
    "2013w46",
    "20131116"
  ]
}

{
  "_id" : 2,
  "value" : 4,
  "d_c_at" : [
    "2013",
    "201311",
    "2013w46",
    "20131116"
  ]
}

{
  "_id" : 3,
  "value" : 6,
  "d_c_at" : [
    "2013",
    "201311",
    "2013w46",
    "20131116"
  ]
}
```